# Setting custom priority for transactions

Tags: transactions

Is it possible to set a different priority for the transactions other than the fee or tip sent? If so, where should I modify the substrate-node to make it work. For example let's say I want to give some account more priority over others, therefore when this account sends a transaction, I want this transaction to be prioritized over the rest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement a custom [`SignedExtension`](https://docs.rs/sp-runtime/latest/sp_runtime/traits/trait.SignedExtension.html) in your runtime that handles this job for you.

```
struct PrioritizeAccount;

impl SignedExtension for PrioritizeAccount {
    type AccountId = AccountId;
    type Call = Call;
    type AdditionalSigned = ();
    type Pre = ();

    fn validate(
        who: &Self::AccountId, 
        _call: &Self::Call, 
        _info: &DispatchInfoOf<Self::Call>, 
        _len: usize,
    ) -> TransactionValidity {
        if who == special_account {
             Ok(ValidTransaction { priority: TransactionValidity::MAX, ..Default::default() })
        } else {
             Ok(Default::default())
        }
    }
}
```

Something like this should do the trick. Then you need to add this to your `SignedExtra` in your runtime `lib.rs` file. But whatever logic you write there, you need to ensure that it is safe and DOS resistant. Otherwise someone could may spam your chain.

Comment: Does this `SignedExtension` need to be added after the transaction-payment extension so that it overrides the priority that is set by transaction-payment-pallet?